# How to provide an object as well as a method reference to an object of that class?

Tags: java, method-reference

I have written a method which creates an input menu for the console, which displays multiple options for the user to choose from and returns the option which the user has chosen. The method accepts an array of objects, and will display them by calling the `toString()` method on them. The problem is, that in some cases I don't want to call the `toString()` method on these objects, but maybe the `getName()` method. Therefore I want to make it possible to pass a method reference, which can be called on the objects and will return a `String`.
Then I could f.e. pass an array of persons and the `getFullName()` method. The persons would be displayed with their full name on the console, but I would still get the person object returned, I wouldn't have to find the person object by its full name.
Here is my current code for the method:

```
    /**
 * Prints the provided question and the options to choose from
 * 
 * @param question
 *            the question to ask the user
 * @param options
 *            list of objects the user can choose from
 * @return chosen object
 */
public Object getMultipleChoiceResult(String question, List<?> options) {
    int result = 0;

    while (result > options.size() | result < 1) {
        System.out.println(question);
        for (int i = 1; i <= options.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("(" + i + ") " + options.get(i - 1).toString());
        }

        try{
            result = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("wrong input");
                scanner.next();
            }

    }

    return options.get(result - 1);
}
```

Do you understand what I am looking for and is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an interface.

Comment: Yes, but then I could only pass objects as options, which implement this interface. I have some objects I'd like to pass as options which classes are defined in dependencies, therefore I can't edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
public <T> T getMultipleChoiceResult(String question, List<T> options, Function<T, String> toString) {
    // ...
    System.out.println("(" + i + ") " + toString.apply(options.get(i - 1)));
    // ...
}
```

In your example, you can call it like this:

```
Object result = getMultipleChoiceResult(question, options, Object::toString);
```

Or you can pass a list of `Person` and print `Person.getFullName()`:

```
Person result = getMultipleChoiceResult(question, persons, Person::getFullName);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! I have one question: Is it right, that I have to cast the return to the specific type? In your example: Person result = (Person) getMultipleCh...

Comment: No, the generic type should do that automatically if you pass a `List<Person>`.

Comment: yep your right, my fault. I forgot to change the return type to "T" :/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of achieving this. A relatively modern approach is to pass a [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```
private static <T> void showList(List<T> list, Function<T,String> f) {
    for (T t : list) {
        System.out.println(f.apply(t));
    }
}
```

The call to this method would look as follows:

```
showList(myList, MyType::getFullName);
```

The above assumes that `myList` is a `List<MyType>`, and `MyType` has a non-static method `getFullName()` returning a `String`.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/TAWCUI)